# ANDROID send mail with attachment file

Tags: java, android, email

I try to create a functionality: send a mail with an attachment file - but it does not work.

I have tried several algo on the web, but no fountain I can't add my attachment automatically. ?

I work on tablet.

I enable the permission in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Thank you for the help.

my code :

```
Java.io.File PayslipDir = new java.io.File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/temp/");
String strFilename = "test.pdf";
java.io.File htmlFile = new java.io.File(PayslipDir, strFilename);
//Uri htmlUri = Uri.fromFile(htmlFile);
Uri htmlUri= Uri.parse("file://" + strFile);
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"contact@gmail.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Pdf attachment");
if (htmlUri != null) {
   //emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,htmlUri);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,htmlUri);
}
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi PDF is attached in this mail. ");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."));
```

sometime i have a crash :

log :

> android.os.FileUriExposedException:
> file:///storage/emulated/0/temp/test.pdf exposed beyond app through
> ClipData.Item.getUri()
> at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1978)
> at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2371)
> at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:966)
> at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10947) ....